# GitHub Actions: How can I automate build artifacts for tag?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I currently have the following yaml file to install build dependencies, build, and create build artifacts whenever the master branch is updated or a commit is pushed to a pull request. I want to add the ability to add build artifacts to a release whenever I create a new tag. I've seen the [create release](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-release) action that seems reasonable. I understand that I could make a new yaml file that runs

```
on: 
  push:
    tags:
```

but I don't want to have to duplicate the logic to install build dependencies and build. Is there a way I can re-use the logic to setup and build to achieve this?

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.CI_PAT }}
          submodules: recursive
          fetch-depth: 0
          
      - name: install dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt install gcc-arm-none-eabi srecord clang-format
          pip install cmake cmake-format
      
      - name: compile
        run: cmake --preset default && cmake --build --preset default

      - name: lint
        run: |
          find . \( -name *.c -o -name *.h \) -not -path "*/ext/*" -not -path "*/build/*" -exec clang-format -style=file --dry-run --Werror {} +
          find . \( -name CMakeLists.txt -o -name *.cmake \) -not -path "*/ext/*" -not -path "*/build/*" -exec cmake-format --check {} +
      - name: upload binaries
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: binaries
          path: build/bin
```

Comment: Have you looked at reusable workflows?

Comment: Yes I have. Seems like you can't use a reusable workflow in a `steps` field of a job though. i.e. have a job that runs the build and then uploads the release binaries is not possible.

Comment: But you could have one job that builds and uploads the binaries and another that downloads the binaries and does whatever else you want to do with a release?